# Finding the mean of elements that meet certain criteria using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and I need to use Python and Pandas to find the average prices of specific items in a column that meet specific criteria. The criteria are "Honda" and "Toyota" in the "manufacturer" column, "good" in the "condition" column, and "sedan" in the "type" column. The prices are in the "price" column. I would then need to return the specific values into a tuple.

I know I need to use groupby() but i'm not sure what else to do

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("vehicles.csv")
def get_avg_prices():
df.groupby(['criteria','manufacturer','condition']).['price'].mean
```

This is how I started but not sure where to go from here or if this is right

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html have a look... after def in the next line it should have a 'tab' so that line of code become part of the function...

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html?highlight=rows%20filtering%20columns here is a good tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You may filter the dataframe columns values with the required criteria conditions:

```
filtered_df = df[df['manufacturer'].isin(['Honda','Toyota']) & (df['condition'] == 'good') & (df['type'] == 'sedan')]
```

After that you can find the mean of the filtered dataframe using groupby:

```
filtered_df.groupby(['manufacturer','condition']).['price'].mean()
```